# PHP Notice: Undefined variable in array_walk_recursive function

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code for download my files :

```
$id = '251';
$type = 'download';
$post_type = 'news';
$file_name = 'C_3.docx';

$files = _files_list_($id,$type);

print_r($files);

array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value) {

    if (false !== stripos($value, $file_name)) { // LINE 17
        $file = ABSPATH.'/uploads/files/'. _is_file_author($id,$type,$post_type).'/'.$value.'';
        ( new Downloader( $file ) )->download();
        echo $file;
    }
});
```

`print_r($files)` :

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => docs/manager.zip ) [1] => Array ( [0] => docs/C_3.docx ) )`

But in Action i see this error (not detect `$id` , `$type`, `$file_name`, `$post_type`):

Notice: Undefined variable: file_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmd\modules\download.php on line 17

how do fix this error?

Comment: `$file_name` is out of scope here. You need to `use` it. So do something like this `..function($value) use ($file_name)`. And as @DeDee said, it could very well be undefined. But in the context above, it's just out of scope.

Comment: andrew, post it as answer please

Comment: Eh, I'm good. Imaginary internet points don't really tickle me right anyway.

Comment: @Andrew: error fix, but not detect $id , $type, $file_name, $post_type in `array_walk_recursive`

Comment: Makes sure you use all the variables and also make sure they contain some sort of value.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value) use ($file_name, $post_type, $type, $id)`, because every single variable outside of the scope cannot be used inside the scope, I would suggest you to pack the variables inside an array and "use" it inside your array_walk_recursive.

Comment: Pass the non detected variables in the function as parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308935/php-notice-undefined-variable-in-array-walk-recursive-function#comment52492929_32308935) post good comments and @[briosheje](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308935/php-notice-undefined-variable-in-array-walk-recursive-function/32309370#comment52493324_32308935) send complete comments:

i change

```
array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value)
```

to

```
array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value) use ($file_name, $post_type, $type, $id),
```

this worked now.

Comment: Also note that, superglobals like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc... are accessible without passing with `use`. So, you can directly use them